# Give a user permission to run sudo without password on some operators

Tags: ubuntu, shell, sudo

I have a `deploy` user. I'm trying to make it to execute some operators without using sudo that i could enter a password for.

here's my `visudo`:

```
# /etc/sudoers
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.

Defaults        env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Uncomment to allow members of group sudo to not need a password
# (Note that later entries override this, so you might need to move
# it further down)
# %sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
%team   ALL=(ALL)     ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# ubuntu user is default user in ec2-images.
# It needs passwordless sudo functionality.
ubuntu  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

Cmnd_Alias DEPLOY= /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/foreman, /sbin/start, /sbin/stop, /sbin/restart, /bin/mv
deploy ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:DEPLOY
```

and here's where `deploy` belongs:

```
ec2 ~: groups deploy
deploy : deploy team
```

I tried `mv` to move some file to `/etc` and it did't work.

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to permit arbitrary moving of files on the filesystem?  Are you sure this cannot be handled by filesystem permissions?  What would prevent an evil person from just doing a `sudo mv /tmp/blah /etc/sudoers`?  If you are going to permit arbitrary file manipulations, you might as well give up, and just permit anything.

Comment: Sooo... what's the problem? Can you show the command you ran and the result?

Comment: By the way, did you mean 'sudo without sudo' or 'sudo without password'?

Comment: You generally don't want to give someone sudo access to `/bin/mv` - since that's a huge security risk.

Giving them sudo access to a script that does the entire task is a lot safer (it's not OK if you give them access to edit said script).

Comment: On that note, giving them sudo access to a script in their home directory really means 'sudo access to EVERYTHING'.

Comment: running `mv xxx /etc`
`mv: cannot move 'xxx' to '/etc/xxx': Permission denied`. I need it for some deployment sake such moving some upstart files to `/etc/init` and running them

Answer (score 1):

> mv xxx /etc

Even if you specify what you did in your `/etc/sudoers` file, you still need to run sudo in your mv command.

But what you *should* be doing is allowing deploy to run a specific script that does the mv operation, but not allowing arbitrary mv commands.